# Outlook Rules - Matching From

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I have two outlook rules, essentially:
   Match From:  outages.sev1@mycompany.com, Move to Folder called Sev1
   Match From:  outages.sev2@mycompany.com, Move to Folder called Sev2

Looks pretty straight forward, but email addressed to either sev1 or sev2 get caught in the first filer.   It doesn't appear to be doing an exact match.

Now, I know I can fiddle with the rules and match on words in the sender address or match on header data, etc.   But my question is why isn't the match working as expected ... I want to understand how the rules are actually being processed leading to this match not working so I can avoid other use cases in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to set "stop processing more rules" in your rules settings.

Comment: Even if rules did not stop process, why would the second filter matching on outages.sev2@mycompany.com trigger. brian, Check the order of your rules and make sure the first rule is set up correctly. I think it is a simple configuration issue.